# How to have a Storyboard with multiple TableViewControllers with the same design and base class without duplicating design

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, viewcontroller, iboutlet

I want to design an App with three table view controllers connected to a Tab Bar Controller and all the three table view controllers will have the same *MyOwnTableViewController* class as class. Within the code of *MyOwnTableViewController* I will understand in which of the three controllers I am thanks to the View Controller Title. This allows me to avoid duplicating code and logic which is common among the three controllers. From the Storyboard point of view do I have to replicate the cell's design in each controller? If I create an *IBOutlet* to reference a cell's label within the first Table View Controller and the same outlet is needed in the other two controllers (since they have the same design and almost the same logic behind) can I connect the same cell's label also of the other two controllers to the previous IBOutlet?

Comment: It's a bad idea to rely on the view controller's title. Make a subclass, add properties, and reuse that.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Thank you for the suggestion.. what about storyboard? Do I need to do all the design three times? Furthermore, suppose that common code needs to write to a label outlet, can I have a var myLabel : UILabel in the main class from which the three UITableViewController inherit from and then override that var with an outlet in each of the three viewControllers? I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I avoid storyboards exactly because it's not straightforward to do that kind of things, and factor as much as I can (usually, everything) in code.